# Subset lines of a data.frame containing a string in another file

Tags: r, string, match, subset

I would like to subset the lines of data frame 1 (df1) that contain a string from a column in data frame 2 (df2). The problem is that file1 will have multiple strings in the same column. I have tried several variations of subset and grep, without success.
Here is an example of the files, and the results I would like to acheive (either would be fine):

df1

```
1 apple A,C,D,F  
2 pear A,D  
3 plum B,F  
4 banana K,P,Z  
5 orange B,C,D,H
```

df2

```
A Jan  
B Feb  
C Mar  
D Apr  
E May  
F Jun  
G Jul  
H Aug  
I Sept  
J Oct
```

Result 1

```
1 apple A,C,D,F  
2 pear A,D  
3 plum B,F  
5 orange B,C,D,H
```

Result 2

```
1 apple A,C,D,F Jan,Mar,Apr,Jun  
2 pear A,D Jan,Apr  
3 plum B,F Feb,Jun  
5 orange B,C,D,H Feb,Mar,Apr,Aug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably be done in multiple steps, but here it is in one line:

```
df1[sapply(strsplit(as.character(df1[,3]),','),function(x) sum(x %in% as.character(df2[,1]))>0),]
```

The `strsplit()` function splits the values in column 3 of `df` using the delimiter `,` and returns a list that looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "A" "C" "D" "F"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "D"

[[3]]
[1] "B" "F"

[[4]]
[1] "K" "P" "Z"

[[5]]
[1] "B" "C" "D" "H"
```

Now we want to check if each element of that list has at least one value in column 1 of `d2`.  One way to do this is to use `%in%`.  If we put the output from our `strsplit()` into `l1` we could test the element of the list like this:

```
l1[[1]] %in% df2[,1]
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

But we only need to know if one is true:

```
sum(l1[[1]] %in% df2[,1])>0
[1] TRUE
```

Since we want to apply this over all the elements of the list and return a vector, I put this into a function and used `sapply()`.  As with everything, there's probably a faster and cleaner way to do it, but this is one way.

Comment: Thank you Tom. I have tried this, but get the following error  Error in strsplit(df1[,3],",") : non-character argument

Comment: @ChrisDias I updated the first line of code.  Chances are the data in your frame are integer instead of character.  In order to make these comparisons work they should be made on character values.

Comment: Thank you Sam. I had already tried transforming all the variables into characters thinking that was the problem, but it had not worked apart from changing my dataframe into a different type of object all together! As you included it above it worked like a charm. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

With @AnandaMahto's `splitstackshape` package, the task is made easier. In this approach we use `merge` after separating the target column into rows. Please be sure that you do not have factors. You can check with `sapply(df1, class)`. You can readin your data without factors with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or `df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
df1.long <- cSplit(df1, "V3", direction="long")
m <- merge(df2, df1.long, by.x='V1', by.y='V3')
result2 <- aggregate(. ~ V2.y, m, toString)
#     V2.y         V1               V2.x
# 1  apple A, C, D, F Jan, Mar, Apr, Jun
# 2 orange B, C, D, H Feb, Mar, Apr, Aug
# 3   pear       A, D           Jan, Apr
# 4   plum       B, F           Feb, Jun
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text="1 apple A,C,D,F  
2 pear A,D  
3 plum B,F  
4 banana K,P,Z  
5 orange B,C,D,H", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df1 <- df[-1]

df2 <- read.table(text="A Jan  
B Feb  
C Mar  
D Apr  
E May  
F Jun  
G Jul  
H Aug  
I Sept  
J Oct ", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```